# Check if the time distance is between different times

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I made a countdown using javascript and php from my functions the countdown works but  now I want to have 3 options:

1. if the countdown is longer than 24 hours show te `selector.next(".countdown").html(expiry);`   date
2. if the countdown is 6 hours or less show the timer `selector.next(".countdown").html(days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ");`
3. else the countdown is less than 0 show that the endend `selector.next(".countdown").html(<p>Closed</p>);`

```
$(".expiry").each(function() {
    var expiry = new Date($(this).text());
    var selector = $(this)
    var x = setInterval(function() {
        var currentDateObj = new Date();
        var numberOfMlSeconds = currentDateObj.getTime();
        var addMlSeconds = 60 * 60 * 1000;
        var now = new Date(numberOfMlSeconds - addMlSeconds);

        var distance = expiry - now;
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        if( distance >= 86400000 && distance < 21600000){
          selector.next(".countdown").html(expiry);  
        }else if ( distance <= 21600000 && distance > 0){
          selector.next(".countdown").html(days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s "); 
        }else{
          selector.next(".countdown").html('<p>error</p>');
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: `86400000` is never smaller than `21600000`, the condition never passes. Maybe you need `||` here instead of `&&` ..?

Comment: It always shows error now btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the first line of your IF statement correct?  Are you wanting to check if it's between those 2 numbers?  If so, should the condition not be:

```
if(distance <= 86400000 && distance > 21600000)
```

I.E. If the distance is ***LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO*** 86400000 AND ***GREATER THAN*** 21600000

At the moment you're checking if distance is both ***GREATER THAN OR EQUAL TO 86400000*** and ***LESS THAN 21600000*** which will always produce false

EDIT
See full if statement block with condition for **GREATER THAN 86400000**

```
if (distance > 86400000) {
    selector.next(".countdown").html('<p>A LOOOOOONG Way off expiring</p>');            
}
else if (distance <= 864000000 && distance > 432000000) { 
    selector.next(".countdown").html(expiry); 
}
else if (distance <= 432000000 && distance > 0) {
    selector.next(".countdown").html(days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s "); 
}
else if (distance < 0) { 
    selector.next(".countdown").html('<p>afgelopen</p>'); 
}
else { 
    selector.next(".countdown").html('<p>Error</p>'); 
}
```

Comment: I got this and still getting erros

   if( distance <= 864000000  && distance > 432000000  ){
    selector.next(".countdown").html(expiry);  
   }else if ( distance <= 432000000 && distance > 0 ){
    selector.next(".countdown").html(days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s "); 
   }else if ( distance < 0) {
    selector.next(".countdown").html('<p>afgelopen</p>');
   }else{
    selector.next(".countdown").html('<p>Error</p>');
   }

Comment: @Bent Just for clarity, when you say error, do you mean the Error selector or an actual error on the page

Comment: Like the Error selector the last else in the if else

Comment: @Bent Have you verified the value of _distance_ by any chance to verify you're getting the value you expect for distance?  Change the Error selector to  _selector.next(".countdown").html(distance);_ and this will print the value of distance instead of the word Error.  What did you get back?

Comment: values like 1202192152 

So this should be the distance between the dates in ms

Comment: @Bent so the code is working fine, you're just not catching a condition when Distance is Greater than 86400000.  _if (distance > 86400000) { DO SOMETHING HERE }.  I've added a condition to the the entire block in my answer above for your reference

Comment: Yea, I saw the samething hahaha, still thanks alot!